# ARcore export point cloud for postprocessing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, point-clouds, arcore

I tried the ARcore sample projekt HelloAR in Unity. Now my aim is to efficiently export the mapped point cloud for postprocessing.

In the sample HelloAR Unity projekt, I changed the ["PointcloudVisualizer.cs"](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/HelloAR/Scripts/PointcloudVisualizer.cs) Script. Now on every Update I copy the current Point Cloud in a Vector4 List.

```
Frame.PointCloud.CopyPoints(pointcloud_temp);
pointcloud_all.AddRange(pointcloud_temp);
```

Then I created a export button which creats onclick a text file out of the "pointcloud_all" list.

1. Is this the propper way of exporting the point cloud from ARcore or did I missed an easier function in the api?
2. Am I right that in the Frame.PointCloud only the point cloud from the current frame is saved? Is somewhere the whole point cloud saved?
3. The Unity ARcore vector4 has as forth component the confidence. How is this measured? And are low values better then high?
4. Has someone experienc with ARcore mapping and has some tips for me?
5. In my next step I'll compare the ARcore point cloud from a room with a real 3d laser scanning point cloud. Has someone already did this and has some results?

I'm using:
ARCore SDK v1.1.0 for and Unity 2017.4.0f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What's your definition of postprocessing? Are you attempting to run additional processing while your app is running, or are you trying to download the data to play with locally on your computer? If the former, you shouldn't write to a text file. Keep in mind the positions are relative to the camera transform.
2. Yes, point clouds are relative to each frame, there's no global point cloud (or global mesh) support (yet?)
3. It's based on some heuristic that ARCore computes. Higher is better. (think of it as a percentage, I'm 90% sure this is a valid point cloud point).
4. Are you trying to reconstruct the room? Are you trying to do it in real time? It's the same problem as lidar systems used in autonomous vehicles. Essentially if you see multiple cloud points at the same spot over successive frames, there's a high likely-hood that that point is real (probably the same heuristic that ARCore uses).
5. Ahh this answers a few of the questions above. The toughest part will be aligning your cloud-point generated version of the room with your lidar-scanned representation. But otherwise, other than the fact that single camera visual-inertial odometry will give you noisier points than a lidar-based scan, you should be able to match one with the other w/ some error

Comment: 3. You're sure about that? I just looked at a test scann and when I look at the points with a confidence in range from [0, 0.15] the resulting point cloud looks much better as when I look at the points in range of 0.85 to 1.
1./4. Yes I'm trying to reconstruct a room in postprocess on my computer, should have mentioned that at the begining of my question.
Does ARcore use SLAM to detect the feature points? And is it possible to change settings of SLAM to get more points detected?

Comment: Okay you were right about the confidence value @ACVM Maybe I filtered something wrong. From the reference doc: _The coordinate system and units of the position values depend on the source of the point cloud data. The confidence value is between 0.f and 1.f, inclusive, with 0 representing 0% confidence and 1.f representing 100% confidence in the measured position values._ [link to doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD)